# Understanding the fmt package in go

Tags: loops, syntax, go, stdout, stdin

**Where comes the `2` from in the output ?**

I wrote a program that reads from STDIN and return values to STDOUT.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var steps, i, a, b int
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &steps)
    for i = 0; i <= steps; i++ {
        fmt.Scanf("%d", &a)
        fmt.Scanf("%d", &b)
        fmt.Println(a + b)
    }
}
```

I have a input file

```
2
2 5
4           8
```

When I run the program with `go run program.go < input` I get:

```
2
7
12
```

Instead of:

```
7
12
```

Why ?

Comment: If I fix the bug with `<=` I get the expected output.

Comment: Can you paste your code ? After the fix ```i < steps``` I get ```2 7``` but no ```12```

Comment: Well, it is just a copy of your code and input file.

Comment: I'd note that this code with more explicit formatting works fine, but I can't articulate why yours doesn't work as intended so I won't answer: http://play.golang.org/p/BGEa9zns3Y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After having tried it, it turns out that (on my Linux machine) if the input file is in "Windows format", with CRLF line ends, it will give your behaviour. If the input file is in "Unix format, with LF line ends, it works as expected. You also get the same behaviour if you add garbage at the end of the lines, for example like this:

```
2x
2 5x
4           8x
```

So it seems that it doesn't recognise CR as a whitespace character, which can be skipped by the "%d" format specifier, and stops reading when it finds it, like it does with the x in my example above.

I think this should be called a bug. It certainly is inconvenient, since it isn't uncommon to encounter text files that happen to have Windows-style line ends when working on Linux.

Comment: You're right, the input is wrong (not \n only) formatted.

Comment: Maybe open an issue? I don't think this is documented or intentional https://github.com/golang/go/issues

Comment: In fact, the line "In all the scanning functions, a carriage return followed immediately by a newline is treated as a plain newline (\r\n means the same as \n)." in the fmt documentation strongly implies otherwise

Comment: Although it's a bug in Go, I accept this answer, because you found what the issue is. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not a language lawyer, but shouldn't you give the `\n`  in the scanf format string? If you give a `\n`, then as the package documentation says, it does not matter if you provide `\r\n` or `\n`, like here: http://play.golang.org/p/NlBL8itLaq . Doc says: *Scanf, Fscanf and Sscanf require newlines in the input to match newlines in the format; the other routines treat newlines as spaces.*

Comment: @siritinga: I am even less of a Go language lawyer, and I have only the vaguest knowledge of the language, but even without the newlines in the format strings, shouldn't it work the same for CRLF and LF? If the newlines in the input are LF instead of CRLF, it works without newlines in the format strings.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy Not necessarily, because Go needs to know that it is looking for a newline to interpret CRLF and LF as the same end of line. If you are looking for something else, it would be very bad if you cannot read the input as is.

Answer (score 0):

`i <= steps` should be `i < steps`.

Comment: thanks, but the problem still occurs with the leading ```2```